# Crashing binary when building with for PPC

Tags: c++, linker, powerpc

i am developing a program for some board, which uses PowerPC Architechture. I just have made some changes to the repository, refactored a bit and moved and erased classes.

On my development machine (VM linux x64) the binaries build fine and are executable. When i build with the CorssCompile Toolchain, it runs through smoothly without any errors nor warnings. But on the target system i cannot get the program to run, it seems to be not even making it to the main entry point.

So my guess is, that i have somehow created a linkage problem in the project. I just don't know how to untangle that beast.

So my questions, how can i get to the bottom of errors that occur before the main entry point was reached. How can i find the possible circular dependencies existing.

And just for "fun": Why in gods name would it build and run on x86 but not on ppc.

Yes i know this is few information to really help out, but i am asking for directions, sort of. Since i will have to deal with these problems some times anyways.

Comment: It seems the PPC toolchain or rather its compiler did not know how to handle static variables being declared after usage (in the same class). Whereas the x86 compiler had no problem parsing such input. (Versions of the compilers where different, the PPC thisng was v4.0.X whereas the x86 was at 5.X.X.)

Comment: To find the error i did: On Target: "gdb crashing/app" and then look at the frames, somewhere there is a "__static_initialization_and_destruction_0" frame, which should even point you to the file and line the yet undeclared static variable is used. A core dump is useless in this situation, since the dump cannot access PC variables. It will not show you any information at all (so it seems, maybe i was using gdb "wrong(not to it's fullest").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why in gods name would it build and run on x86 but not on ppc.

There are a million possible reasons, from broken cross-toolchain, to bugs in libc, to incorrect toolchain invocation.

> i am asking for directions

You should start by compiling this source:

```
int main() { return 0; }
```

and verifying that it works (this verifies basic toolchain sanity). If it does, you then extend it to print something. Then compile it with exactly the flags that you use in your real project.

If all of that checks out, you can run your real project under `strace` and/or GDB and see if you understand where the crash is happening. If you don't, edit your question with output from the tools, and someone may be able to guess better.

**Update:**

> It seems the PPC toolchain or rather its compiler did not know how to handle static variables being declared after usage

If that were true, you would get a compilation error. You didn't, so this is false.

> On Target: "gdb crashing/app" and then look at the frames, somewhere there is a "__static_initialization_and_destruction_0" frame, which should even point you to the file and line the yet undeclared static variable is used.

Your *real* problem is very likely this: order of construction of global (or class-static) variables in different translation units (i.e. different source files) is undefined (and usually is opposite between `x86_64` and `ppc`). If you have two such globals in different files (say `A` and `B`), and if `B`s constructor depends on `A` having been constructed already, then your program will work fine on platforms where `A` is constructed before `B`, but will crash on platforms where `B` is attempted to be constructed before `A`.

Comment: This points in the right direction, a bit of explaining how to would be nice though, anyways, the real problem is described in the comment on my question.

Comment: @MDeero I've updated the answer. Re: "a bit of explaining" -- you didn't provide any information to know where to begin explaining anything.

Comment: Seriously, it is as i described! You cannot correct me on something i have just witnessed, the ONLY thing i did to get rid of the error was to move the line of a static variable declaration up before its use (in a declaration of another static variable) in the SAME source file. AND YES, i was exactly as bluffed as you, i would expect it to produce an compilation error, well it didn't. Instead it just wouldn't run. (I could have also get rid of the error by updating the compiler i guess, but since it's cross-compile, i don't wanna mess with anything there)

Comment: @MDeero You are likely *still* mistaken. Moving the declaration up *also* changes the order of construction with respect to other variables declared in the same file. In any case, your explanation doesn't make any sense, and so is very unlikely to be correct.

Comment: cmake version 3.2.2;  GNU Make 3.81;  CROSS_COMPILE: powerpc-poky-linux-gnuspe-g++ (GCC) 4.8.1;  LOCAL_COMPILE: g++ (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2) 5.2.1 20151010... if you wanna test it, the failing one is the ppc toolchain compiler, which seems to fail to take care of declaration orders